# Round the third decimal place up into the second decimal place (e.g. $0.033 becomes $0.04)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

When we increased the price with 10%, some products (the ones that have 3 decimal points), got an unwanted price change. For example, an item that had a price of `0.03` changed to `0.033`.

Our client doesn't want a three decimal point in the pricing.

We want to round the third decimal place up into the second decimal place (e.g. `$0.033` becomes `$0.04`).

If my value is `0.033`, I want result to be `0.04`.

Please help me

Regards

Amit Vyas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative way to do it would be `CEILING(n * 100) / 100`

Answer (score 0):

Please used this

```
ROUND ( 0.335 , 2 )
```

This will work in my database

Regards
Paras